# what is the best way to parsing the logs for .log and .json format

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

i am planning to prepare the one pipeline for different logs formatting.

1. .json format
2. .log format
   these are two type of logs which i need to create filter and grok patterns.
   what is the good ways please suggest.

i tried to follow the

```
filter 
{
    codec = json
    source = "message" 
}
```

but when i am trying to filter the .log format logstash is not going filter those except plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to separate the different log types to different logstash pipelines, in this way you have more control on filtering.

Here you can find the documentation on creating multiple pipelines:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

Comment: i understand but i have to combined all logs format in one pipelines. can we combine the .json and .logs format in the same pipelines ?

Comment: Maybe try to explain what is your use case exactly. You can configure the output of a pipeline to be a different pipeline. You can also output the data to the same elastic index and the view the data as one. You can also create 2 inputs for the same pipeline.